# CSS3 - image corner hide behind border radius

Tags: css, css-transitions

How to hide square image (90 degree corner) behind a content cox with border radius.

This is for iPhone mobile app.

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/corner.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/corner.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when the `border-radius` property was first announced by the W3C. You've got to solutions: first, use `background-image` to set the image as your `div`'s background.
Second, would be using `<img class="my-class-rounded-corners" src="myimage">`, appending a class to an `<img>` tag rather than a `div`, then setting rounded corners as a property of that class.

Comment: What about this?
border: 1px #bfeaf0 solid; overflow: hidden;

Comment: First, try to use backticks to mark code in comments. Second, does that include `border-radius`, or did you intentionally leave it out?

Comment: What is backticks? Pardon my ignornace.

Comment: Yes it is included. border: 1px #bfeaf0 solid; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 8px;

Comment: Backticks are accessed when you press the tilde (~) key without holding down shift.
As for your code, the problem isn't overflow; it's just the image fitting the `<div>` in general. You can set overflow to 0, but it'll still have a margin on the left side. Give my advice from earlier a try, and see if it helps.